# MSMQ and WCF contracts - future enhancements

Tags: wcf, msmq

I am creating a WCF service which is bound to an MSMQ. This will be using the MSMQ Integrated binding.

Now the plan is to place the messages on the MSMQ which implements a given interface (i.e: IPerson)

if IPerson has 3 properties:

```
string Name
int Age
string address
```

and a message gets sent using this contract, WCF reads it fine and can process etc...

however, what if we decide in future to add an additional property?

Will WCF fail to process that message and classify it as poison?

How can I make the service so that it is somewhat future compatible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IExtensibileDataObject in your datacontract
You can find more info on msdn:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject.aspx

Comment: If the object implements `IExtensibleDataObject` which means your object will have a property with `ExtensionDataObject` type. When you send the message to MSMQ you will get exception to complain `ExtensionDataObject` is not marked as serializable.